# Dimensionality reduction using UMAP in batches

Tags: javascript, dimensionality-reduction

I'm using the javascript implementation of UMAP (https://github.com/PAIR-code/umap-js#readme) to do dimensionality reduction for 10,000 embeddings (each with 1558 dimensions). I don't want to have to load all this data into memory at once obviously.

Is there any way I can fit the data in batches?